# First time using classes in C++, what's going on?

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a custom tree structure, but I am getting a weird output.

```
enum letter{B,A,T,G,C,N};
struct Node {
    int ltr;
    Node* ptr;
};
class GTree
{

public:
    GTree(int);
    void insert(int);
private:
    Node* root;
    void insert(int l,Node* leaf);
};
GTree::GTree(int l)
{
    root->ltr=l;
}
void GTree::insert(int l, Node *leaf)
{
    cout<<leaf->ltr;
}
void GTree::insert(int l)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        insert(l, root);
    }
    else
    {
        root= new Node;
        insert(l,root);
    }
}
int main()
{
    GTree tree=GTree(T);
    tree.insert(T);
}
```

The output comes out as -2062064467 even though I was expecting 2. Whats going on here? I was looking at a simple BTree implementation, but intending to repurpose it for my desired data structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't create a Node object when you first created the GTree object.

```
GTree::GTree(int l)
{
    root->ltr=l;
}
```

should be

```
GTree::GTree(int l)
{
    root = new Node();
    root->ltr=l;
}
```

Also, make sure you have a destuctor to clean up the resources.

---

Something else I feel I should point out is that `GTree::insert(int l, Node *leaf)` perhaps doesn't do what you expect it to do.

`cout<<leaf->ltr;`

The code above only outputs the integer value in the node but not actually assigning it.

But perhaps you haven't completed that part yet. :-)

Comment: for your edit: I just haven't implemented it for simplicities sake, I am cout'ing just to make sure the early stages are working.

Answer (score 2):

You hadn't initialized root, so `root->ltr=l;` produces undefined behavior. Add `root = new Node();` first.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and got the output 0 on Ubuntu 12.04 with gcc 4.6.3.

Comment: well, it's undefined behavior... :-)